# How to make watercolor illustration effect with white dots in this example?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, vector, photoshop-effects, effects

https://vistria.com/

this site has the effect I am talking about
It's a watercolor illustration image and has a white dotted pattern on its ending and fewer dots on the center
I want to know how to make this effect.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where is that failing? (this is *not* a "tutorial on demand" web site.)

Comment: Thank you for replying, Really appreciate how you give me some of your time to try and answer my question.
I have tried to use (Filters > Neural Filters > Style Transfer > Using a Custom Image from the site) but it didn’t get me the white dotted pattern
So, I tried doing this youtube tutorial _[link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhgTFAUZrMs)_ and using the brush tool to get the white dotted pattern
But, I haven’t managed to get it right yet, I was asking for help on doing this white dotted pattern. This is not a "tutorial on demand" website, but this is where I saw the style I liked

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new layer. Paint to it white with a soft brush. Let the brush have reduced opacity, say max. 30% and blending mode = Dissolve.

I said the brush! The new layer should have 100% opacity and blending mode = Normal.

Apply to the new layer Gaussian Blur 1px or less.

An example:

[image]

The upper dot cloud has got no blur, it's only a couple of brush strokes as described above. There are random white pixels here and there as blending mode Dissolve makes. The bottom side dot cloud has got 0,5px Gaussian blur after painting.

In both cases the brush opacity was 25%. The image (when painted with white) was a 600 px wide randomly selected snippet of a news photo.

Make some tests. The visual result depends much on the pixels per inch of the image. If you have a high resolution image below it's well possible that you must scale the resulted dissolve pattern bigger to make its apparent density and grain size to fit the image below. Do not insert blur before you do the scaling. Scale by using the nearest neighbour resampling mode to keep the dots sharp. Other resampling modes make the dots blurry, but that can also be a good effect.

Answer (score 0):

The image has two parts.

The watercolor itself. That is made using a filter, and there is various vendors that do this. In my opinion, one of the best for that particular look is [Filter Forge](https://www.filterforge.com/more/tutorials/classic/tut-001.html). It is an instalable aplication.

But you can google different ones. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=filter+forge+watercolor

Many are online, some with a free trial.

If you really want to paint watercolor digitally, two options come to my mind. Rebelle, which has a nice online canvas: https://www.escapemotions.com/products/rebelle/try/

and Corel Painter. https://www.painterartist.com/en/product/painter/

---

For the grainy look add some noise and use some brushes.